# Css combinator in div'd unordered list -- javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have a css image gallery based on anchors and hidden images in an unordered list, as below.

```
#gallery {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Gallery:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <ul id="gallery-interior">
    <li id="one"><a href="#two"><img src="../images/intro.jpg"></a></li>
    <li id="two"><a href="#three"><img src="../images/detail.jpg"></a></li>
```

This gallery also has thumbnails beneath that reference the anchors in the list to select images individually, as below

```
<div class='thumbs'>
  <a href="#one"><img src="../images/intro_thumb.jpg"></a>
  <a href="#two"><img src="../images/detail_thumb.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

...and these thumbs are styled to change on selection, as below

```
.thumbs a:active img,
.thumbs a:focus img,
{
    opacity:0.65;
    -moz-opacity:0.65;
    filter:alpha(opacity=65;
)
```

This is all working as intended, but whilst the thumbs respond to selection by changing opacity, I'd like them to also change in response to clicking the links in the list, i.e., clicking `<a href="#two">` at `<li id="one">` would cause 'detail_thumb.jpg' to become opaque.

I believe a CSS combinator is required here, but it's not clear what the syntax would be for applying the `.thumbs a:active img` selector from the list links (`<li id="one"><a href="#two"><img src="../images/intro.jpg"></a></li>`)

Update: Is there an applicable javascript solution, given that I didn't specify pure CSS?

Comment: That can’t be done using CSS alone with an HTML structure like that – there is no “connection” between the links in the list and the thumbnails that CSS would be able to select.

Comment: Thanks for commenting; so the common <a href="#one"> links couldn't be div-containered to provide this functionality? They connect the thumbs to the list gallery, so it's not obvious (to me!) why this connection can't be made to be bi-directional...

Comment: _“so it's not obvious (to me!) why this connection can't be made to be bi-directional... ”_ – because CSS is only able to select elements further down the structure, but not upwards.